# How to set TTL in Java based app for DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I need to set time to live programmatically for a table in DynamoDB via AWS Java SDK. Is it possible? I know that TTL feature is introduced recently - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

**UPDATE:**
There is no special annotaion, but we can do it manually:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute
private long ttl;
```

and configure it as ttl in AWS - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html

```
long now = Instant.now().getEpochSecond(); // unix time
long ttl = 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hours in sec
setTtl(ttl + now); // when object will be expired
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateTimeToLive` documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) or direct link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#updateTimeToLive-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.UpdateTimeToLiveRequest-)

Comment: I'm not sure this link is correct, it just brings me to the root of AWS SDK documentation, which is not terribly useful...

Comment: @JanikZikovsky it's difficult to deep link into the documentation there, but if you go to the link and then search for `AmazonDynamoDBClient`, go to that page then search for `updateTimeToLive` you will find the documentation for updating the TTL setting.

Comment: How about [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#updateTimeToLive-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.UpdateTimeToLiveRequest-) - though it does not have the frames.

Answer (score 10):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html

```html
    public void function(final AmazonDynamoDB client, final String tableName, final String ttlField){

        //table created now enabling TTL
        final UpdateTimeToLiveRequest req = new UpdateTimeToLiveRequest();
        req.setTableName(tableName);

        final TimeToLiveSpecification ttlSpec = new TimeToLiveSpecification();
        ttlSpec.setAttributeName(ttlField);
        ttlSpec.setEnabled(true);
        req.withTimeToLiveSpecification(ttlSpec);

        client.updateTimeToLive(req);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Code Sample [here](http://meethassan.net/2017/03/29/creating-dynamodb-table-with-time-to-live-ttl-using-aws-java-sdk/).

```
  //Then set ttl field like below for days in java
    //ttl 60 days
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //current date and time      
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 60); //add days
    double ttl =  (cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L);
```