# How to make DynamoDB deletes data every hour since the data is created?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB as communication between Lambda and Springboot application.

To prevent the DB growing too big. I want to make the db delete the message in a time interval since they are created. I checked TTL in DynamoDB. It seems that it can only delete data from a date, **not like every hour**.

Is it possible to do that with DynamoDB?

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to delete data on a schedule with DynamoDB alone.

Depending on how much data you’re talking about and where the data is coming from, you could do one of the following:

If you are controlling the process that writes to Dynamo you can make a change such that whenever you write an item to DynamoDB that needs to be cleaned up, you also post a delayed message to an SQS queue. Then, you can have a separate SQS poller that receives the deferred messages from SQS and deletes the corresponding item from DynamoDB.

If you don’t control the part that writes the items to the database (ie they come from IoT etc.) then you could enable streams on the DynamoDB and attach a lambda to process the stream which can either follow the strategy with SQS delayed messages, or use AWS Step Functions to delay a callback to delete the item by an hour.

All this is assuming you can’t use TTL which really is the most economic and efficient solution. With TTL you need to calculate the expiration time when writing the item. And TTL might take up to 48 hours to actually remove the item but if you control both the writer and the consumer of the data, you can have the consumer ignore expired items. And TTL will handle the removal of expired items in the background without additional costs or infrastructure. Only downside is that you have to be deliberate when reading and writing the items to your table.

Comment: I am able to use TTL, but can I set the expire time for each data I insert into DynamoDB? If the code is like link below, each time I insert data into db, I should updateTimeToLive? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812415/how-to-set-ttl-in-java-based-app-for-dynamodb

Comment: Yes, each item has its own expiration timestamp value. TTL is a bit of a misnomer. And yes, whenever you insert an item you must set its expiration time. If you want it to expire after one hour, then you compute that time when you insert the item and store it.

Comment: Are you sure about this. I find the document here:[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#updateTimeToLive-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.UpdateTimeToLiveRequest-) You can't update it every time you add an item into DynamoDB

Comment: Sure about what? Are you referring to enabling TTL for the table? Yes - TTL must be enabled for the whole table by specifying the attribute that will be used as Expiration on each item. But each item has its own expiration value.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand the TTL thing. I thought I need to call a method to use ttl for each item. Just add expire unix time as an attribute for each item.